# How do you prove that multiplying a symmetric function by a constant preserves symmetry?

Tags: functions, proof-verification, symmetry

I'm working on a homework problem and I've realized that if I can solve this sub-problem I will be able to solve the whole problem. I'm not really sure how to tackle this type of proof because I need it to extend to three dimensions. Like logically it makes sense, but how do you go about mathematically proving it?

Comment: Symmetry in what sense?

Comment: Do you mean $af(x)=af(-x)$?

Comment: Hi, in this specific problem it's radial symmetry.

Comment: Could you write out more specifically what you are trying to prove in an equation? Like 
$f(\mathbf{T} x) = f(x) \Rightarrow a f(\mathbf{T} x) = a f(x)$?

Comment: If $x \mapsto f(x)$ has radial symmetry, it can be expressed as a function $x \mapsto g(\|x\|)$ for some other function $g$. If you consider the function $x \mapsto c f(x)$, then it is still radially symmetric since this can be written as $x \mapsto c g(\|x\|)$.

Comment: Well the function is in three dimensions but yeah I guess I can expand the concept. Sorry this was a stupid question lmao.