# Are all functions on a discrete domain radially symmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, symmetry

I came across this question today and am looking for a flaw in this very simple argument of mine.

I'm interested in whether a function $f : \mathcal{X}^n \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ is radially symmetric. I have not done much previous work with radial symmetry but [How do you prove that multiplying a symmetric function by a constant preserves symmetry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038092/how-do-you-prove-that-multiplying-a-symmetric-function-by-a-constant-preserves-s#comment4183754_2038092) claims that a function $f$ is radially symmetric if there exists a function $g$ such that $f(x) = g(\lVert x \rVert)$.

Now, if the domain of $f$ if discrete, i.e. $\mathcal{X}$ is discrete, there exists an injective Gödel encoding $h : \mathcal{X}^n \to \mathbb{N}$ with inverse $h^{-1}$ such that $f = f \circ h^{-1} \circ h$. Wouldn't that yield that if $h$ is a norm which I suppose it is that $f$ is radially symmetric purely because it is defined on a discrete domain?

The statement seems wrong to me, do you see the error in the argument?

Comment: $\|\cdot\|$ is not just "a" norm, it's the usual norm on the domain. If $f(1)=17$ and $f(-1)=42$, then $f$ is not radially symmetric no matter what subset of ${\bf R}^2$ is the domain.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.